# Вывести типы записей custom таксономии Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Не получается вывести зарегистрированные типы записей относящиеся к зарегистрированной таксономии

Делаю так:

```
$args = array
    (
        'taxonomies'    => array('cat_inst')
    );
print_r(get_post_types($args));
```

Выводит пустой массив. Таксономия и тип записи customs.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть нюанс?

Самый главный вопрос у меня, как узнать какие типы записей есть у таксономии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить зарегистрированные типы записей, относящиеся к зарегистрированной таксономии, можно следующим образом:

```
global $wp_taxonomies;
var_dump($wp_taxonomies['product_cat']->object_type);
```

Будет выведен массив зарегистрированных типов. Для WooCommerce, как в примере выше, выводится

```
Array[1]
 0: "product"
```

В качестве обратной задачи - все таксономии, относящиеся к типу записи, можно вывести с помощью такой функции:

```
get_object_taxonomies('product');
```

Для таксономии `product` в WooCommerce получаем такой результат:

```
Array[5]
  0: "product_type"
  1: "product_cat"
  2: "product_tag"
  3: "product_shipping_class"
  4: "pa_color"
```

Comment: Эта функция получает список таксономий относящийся к типу посту, посту и т.д. А мне нужен список типов постов у таксономии.

Comment: Вы вопрос как поставили: "зарегистрированные типы записей относящиеся к зарегистрированной таксономии". Я так и ответил. Приведите конкретный пример, иначе трудно понять, чего вы хотите.

Comment: Вы все перепутали тип поста у вас product, а вывели Вы таксономии прикрепленные к этому типу.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Работает спасибо.
Почему не получается через get_post_types()?

Comment: Не знаю, не лазил в код WP по этому поводу. Где-то видел возглас, что get_post_types () с taxonomies в массиве аргументов не работает.